# How to get access token from refresh token?

Tags: ios, swift, google-api, google-oauth, google-signin

I have an iOS Swift application which uses Google Cloud Prediction API to determine some images. After some predictions the session gets expired and will have to redirect user to sign in page. Instead of redirecting to the sign-in I want the application to get a new access token from refresh token as mentioned in Google Docs [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/offline-access).

I have followed [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start?ver=swift) link for sign-in, and have successfully integrated Google SignIn into our app.
My requirement is to get the access token from refresh token so that if the session expires I can sign in silently using the new token.
Please provide with endpoint details and all the steps to be followed.

I have gone through the steps provided in this [link](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/offline-access). In Step 6, they have provided Server-side code in Java/Python, which is used to get access token from refresh token.  How can I get its REST API details, which can be used from the iOS application?

Comment: First of all, you configured FireApp with all steps in your project?

Comment: @NikunjKumbhani Hi, Did you mean Firebase App?

Comment: Yes Is it completely configure?

Comment: @NikunjKumbhani can you please share the link you are referring to, so that i can cross-check the steps with mine ? thankyou.

Comment: Go with this https://medium.com/xcblog/get-started-with-firebase-for-ios-apps-32a5dc850a28

Comment: @NikunjKumbhani we haven't used Firebase at all, instead followed this link https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in?ver=swift

Comment: This one is for Integrating Google Sign-In in your app and you asked a question about access refresh token so this both are a different thing what exact you want?

Comment: @NikunjKumbhani  We are using Google SignIn referring to above mentioned link, even there we get access token and refresh token, but not sure how to get new access token using refresh token.

Answer (score 0):

The `tokenRefreshNotification` function doesn't always get called when launching the app.

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
import Firebase

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    FirebaseApp.configure()
    return true
}
```

However, when placing the code inside the regular `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` delegate function, I can get the token every time:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    if let refreshedToken = InstanceID.instanceID().token() {
        print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")
    }
}
```